# How did Kyber's authors compute the error probability $\delta$?

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, kyber

I'm studying the specification of [Kyber](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/) that was submitted to [NIST PQC Round 3](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/post-quantum-cryptography/round-3-submissions). However, I cannot figure out how they compute the error probability $\delta$ for Kyber 512, 768 and 1024. I have read the [Kyber paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) (written with respect to round 1), especially its *Theorem 1* (correctness theorem). But the paper did not explain how to compute $\delta$; instead, the author just stated that they "provide with [the] software" a Python script to compute it (which was in neither the paper's appendix [nor, apparently,](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/search?l=python) the software's Git repo).

> $$\begin{array}{c} 
> \text{Table 1: parameter sets for Kyber} \\ \hline
> \begin{array}{l c} 
> & n & k & q & \eta_1 & \eta_2 & (d_u,d_v) & \delta \\ \hline
> \text{Kyber512}  & 256 & 2 & 3329 & 3 & 2 & (10,4)  & 2^{-139} \\
> \text{Kyber768}  & 256 & 3 & 3329 & 2 & 2 & (10,4)  & 2^{-164} \\
> \text{Kyber1024} & 256 & 4 & 3329 & 2 & 2 & (11,55) & 2^{-174}
> \end{array} \\ \hline
> \end{array}$$

Can one explain how $\delta$ is computed? How accurate or "tight" are these $\delta$ values, and how would one evaluate their correctness?

Comment: The fact that the mentioned script seems *entirely missing* might warrant a quick e-mail to the authors -- be sure to mention that it's not in the appendix, and that their Git repo apparently doesn't contain any Python scripts.

Comment: The scripts are here - sorry they're not more easy to find.
https://github.com/pq-crystals/security-estimates

Comment: @VadimL. Thanks. After studying the code (even read the comments in the script), I think I cannot quite get the overall spirit for how such error probability is computed. Need some help.

Comment: To understand the technique for how one calculates the exact error in Kyber-like schemes, take a look at Sections 2.3.2 and 4.7 of http://tinyurl.com/latticesurvey